# How to only select objects from a list which satisfy certain conditions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I need to select objects which have certain overlapping properties from a larger set.

I need to select the set of objects which are within a radius of 5 away from the centre, at heights 1-1.25 from the midplane and of different ages. So far I have tried the following, however it does not seem to work as needed, in particular it does not seem to be affected by the height selection (which it definitely should). The selected stars must satisfy all conditions.

```
bulge=s.s[s.s['rxy']<5]

height=[i for i, x in enumerate(bulge['z']) if 1<x<1.25]
age1=[i for i, x in enumerate(bulge['age']) if x<0.1]
age2=[i for i, x in enumerate(bulge['age']) if 9<x<10]

ageheight1=bulge(height and age1)
ageheight2=bulge(height and age2)
```

Below are radial density distributions for different heights

[height from 0.75-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDJ7w.png)

[height from 1-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D2BX.png)

One can see that the height does not affect the result at all, which should not be the case.

Comment: post the sample data and expected output

Comment: What datatype is s? Are you using pandas or numpy? Can you post examples of the input and expected output compared to the incorrect output you get.

Comment: s is the stars component of a pynbody galaxy simulation. It is too large to upload here (several gigabytes). I think my problem has to do with a lack of understanding on how to write python conditions.

Comment: Yes, but What datatype is s? Are you using pandas or numpy?

Comment: Pynbody uses numpy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the datatype you are working with is a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) then you can compose conditional statements and select using this as follow

```
ageheight1 = bulge[ (bulge['age']<0.1) & (bulge['z']<1.25) & (bulge['z']>1)]
ageheight2 = bulge[ (bulge['age']<10) & (bulge['age']>9) & (bulge['z']<1.25) & (bulge['z']>1)]
```